# cfwebsocket working example on android phone browser?

Tags: android, websocket, coldfusion-10

I been putting together some of the CFWEBSOCKET demos I found on the web. I can get them working on iOS and with different browsers fine. Yet when I try my Android phones S3 and Xoom they don't connect correctly with any of the Demos I found online.

I been searching but don't see any comments on using CFWEBSOCKETS for a Android Phone Web Application. Has anyone ran into this issue? I see Websockets work using the Echo Test from Google so it has to be something with CFWEBSOCKET coldfusion tag.